# Function Failing at Large List Sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question: Starting with a 1-indexed array of zeros and a list of operations, for each operation add a value to each the array element between two given indices, inclusive. Once all operations have been performed, return the maximum value in the array.

Example: n = 10, Queries = [[1,5,3],[4,8,7],[6,9,1]]

The following will be the resultant output after iterating through the array, Index 1-5 will have 3 added to it etc...:

```
[0,0,0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0]
[3,3,3, 3, 3,0,0,0,0, 0]
[3,3,3,10,10,7,7,7,0, 0]
[3,3,3,10,10,8,8,8,1, 0]
```

Finally you output the max value in the final list:

```
[3,3,3,10,10,8,8,8,1, 0]
```

My current solution:

```
def Operations(size, Array):
    ResultArray = [0]*size
    Values = [[i.pop(2)] for i in Array]

    for index, i in enumerate(Array):

        #Current Values in       =  Sum between the current values in the Results Array AND the added operation of equal length
        #Results Array
        ResultArray[i[0]-1:i[1]] = list(map(sum, zip(ResultArray[i[0]-1:i[1]], Values[index]*len(ResultArray[i[0]-1:i[1]]))))

    Result = max(ResultArray)
    return Result

def main():

    nm = input().split()

    n = int(nm[0])

    m = int(nm[1])

    queries = []

    for _ in range(m):
        queries.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    result = Operations(n, queries)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Example input**: The first line contains two space-separated integers n and m, the size of the array and the number of operations.
Each of the next m lines contains three space-separated integers a,b and k, the left index, right index and summand.

```
5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100
```

> Compiler Error at Large Sizes:
> Runtime Error

Currently this solution is working for smaller final lists of length 4000, however in order test cases where length = 10,000,000 it is failing. I do not know why this is the case and I cannot provide the example input since it is so massive. Is there anything clear as to why it would fail in larger cases?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Could it just be memory issues?

Comment: Unaware of what a stack trace is. This is a question posed in HackerRank called Array Manipulation. In case you want to check with the real test case.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: The site would show: Compiler Error - Runtime Error. Thats all I can tell since im not able to run the massive test example myself, im working off what the website is providing.

Comment: As a side note, this sort of problem is not intended to be brute forced as you are currently doing, but rather use a special data structure called a Segment Tree: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)

Comment: Awesome, Ill start looking it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you make too many intermediary trow away list here:

```
ResultArray[i[0]-1:i[1]] = list(map(sum, zip(ResultArray[i[0]-1:i[1]], Values[index]*len(ResultArray[i[0]-1:i[1]]))))
```

this `ResultArray[i[0]-1:i[1]]` result in a list and you do it twice, and one is just to get the size, which is a complete waste of resources, then you make another list with `Values[index]*len(...)` and finally compile that into yet another list that will also be throw away once it is assigned into the original, so you make 4 throw away list, so for example lets said the the slice size is of 5.000.000, then you are making 4 of those or 20.000.000 extra space you are consuming, 15.000.000 of which you don't really need, and if your original list is of 10.000.000 elements, well just do the math...

You can get the same result for your list(map(...)) with list comprehension like

```
[v+Value[index][0] for v in ResultArray[i[0]-1:i[1]] ]
```

now we use two less lists, and we can reduce one list more by making it a generator expression, given that slice assignment does not need that you assign a list specifically, just something that is iterable

```
(v+Value[index][0] for v in ResultArray[i[0]-1:i[1]] )
```

I don't know if internally the slice assignment it make it a list first or not, but hopefully it doesn't, and with that we go back to just one extra list

here is an example

```
>>> a=[0]*10
>>> a
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> a[1:5] = (3+v for v in a[1:5])
>>> a
[0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

we can reduce it to zero extra list (assuming that internally it doesn't make one) by using itertools.islice

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a[3:7] = (1+v for v in itertools.islice(a,3,7))
>>> a
[0, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```